# python time.time() differences in python 2 vs 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-internals, gettimeofday

I am wondering why `python 2.7` uses `gettimeofday()` when running `time.time()` but yet in `python 3.4` it does not?

It appears when running strace that it may be querying /etc/localtime

Comment: do u face any problem with it ?

Comment: Is there any problem with the different implementation? The Python 3 `time` module was overhauled when the various new clock types were added.

Comment: Yes using the virtual time kernel https://github.com/littlepretty/VirtualTimeKernel

Which relies on GToD

Comment: Also the docs are misleading suggesting that if available it should use GToD https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html

Comment: The documentation is not lying; perhaps you need to build Python directly on your system instead? See the [`pygettimeofday()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/pytime.c#l451) specifically.

Comment: Specifically, what does `import time; print(time.get_clock_info('time'))` produce for your system?

Comment: namespace(adjustable=True, implementation='clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)', monotonic=False, resolution=1e-09)

Comment: @channon: right, so your system uses the newer `clock_gettime()` function, as it well should. I see that `VirtualTimeKernel` supports that function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 will use `gettimeofday()` when your system has been detected to support this *at compile time*. However, on POSIX systems it'll only use that if [`clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) is not available instead; according to the [POSIX 2008 standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) the latter is preferred as `gettimeofday()` is considered obsolete.

At runtime, you can query what Python thought your system could support at compile time by using the [`time.get_clock_info()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.get_clock_info), which returns a `namedtuple` instance with a `implementation` field:

> *implementation*: The name of the underlying C function used to get the clock value

On my OSX 10.11 system, for the `'time'` clock, that produces `gettimeofday()`:

```
>>> time.get_clock_info('time').implementation
'gettimeofday()'
```

You can read through the [`pygettimeofday()` C implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Python/pytime.c#l451) to see what implementations may be used; on Windows `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` is used for example.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try to force it to use GToD as its clocking mechanism.

Comment: @channon: not sure why you'd need to as I see [VirtualTimeKernel supports `clock_gettime()`](https://github.com/littlepretty/VirtualTimeKernel/blob/7d3b11be676df5e828f9c52b34990ebc55330e72/arch/x86/vdso/vclock_gettime.c).

Comment: because the virtual time only effects GToD it is in the code for that function